# VisualStudio просит объявить API (библиотека VK C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vkontakte-api, visual-c++, curl

Приветствую всех,

Пытаюсь разобраться с одной [библиотекой](https://github.com/Kolsha/VK), подключающей VK API к C++. С плюсами я знаком очень поверхностно (как и с программированием в целом), но то, что мне нужно, много знаний и не требует (мне там несколько циклов просто написать). Буду очень благодарен за помощь :3

*Я ещё поставил Curl, как просит автор библиотеки, хотя не знаю, что конкретно он делает, может проблема в этом.*

Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "external/src/api.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string access_token = 'Мой токен'
    string pass = "Мой пароль от аккаунта ВК";
    string login = "Мой номер телефона";
    if (api.auth(login, pass, access_token)) {
        cout << "Auth ok" << endl;
        cout << "Access token: " << api.access_token() << endl << endl;
        cout << api.call("wall.post", "owner_id='Мой ID'&message=Test");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Auth fail" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот, что отвечает компилятор:

```
error C2065: api: необъявленный идентификатор
error C2228: выражение слева от ".auth" должно представлять класс, структуру
```

или объединение
    note: тип: unknown-type
    error C2065: api: необъявленный идентификатор
    error C2228: выражение слева от ".access_token" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
    note: тип: unknown-type
    error C2065: api: необъявленный идентификатор
    error C2228: выражение слева от ".call" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
     note: тип: unknown-type

Ещё раз большое спасибо за помощь новичку ^_^ Буду очень благодарен, если объясните в чём моя ошибка и посоветуете, что прочитать, чтобы больше не спотыкаться.

*Пользуюсь Vusial Studio 2017*

Comment: Давно уже с этой библиотекой вожусь. Даже винду поставил на мак, потому что на OS X на Atom'е какая-то ошибка с json была. Тут её, похоже, нет

Answer (score 1):

Вы, когда код переписываете, то делайте это с пониманием :)

Вы, скорее всего, тянули отсюда:

```
VK::Client api;
api.set_fa2_callback(fa2_callback);
api.set_cap_callback(captcha_callback);
if(api.auth(login, pass, access_token)){
```

Видите - в первой строке объявлена переменная `api`? А у вас эта переменная не объявлена.

Представьте - вы написали

```
int main()
{
    x = 5.0;
}
```

Что вам компилятор скажет? Что переменная `x` не объявлена, он не знает ее типа и что с ней делать. Слово в слово он говорит то же о вашей `api`.

Comment: Сейчас перезайду с Windows и попробую, спасибо большое ^_^